# Is laravelcollective/annotations compatible to laravel 5.5?

Tags: php, laravel-5.5, laravelcollective

I want know if `LaravelCollective/annotations` is compatible with the 5.5.34 version of `laravel`... I didn't see any information about it in the laravelcollective's official site.

When I try to install it with

```
composer require laravelcollective/annotations
```

And I have this error :

```
  Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v5.5.34
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.34
    - laravelcollective/annotations v5.4.0 requires illuminate/filesystem 5.4.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/filesystem[v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9].
    - laravelcollective/annotations v5.4.1 requires illuminate/filesystem 5.4.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/filesystem[v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9].
    - laravelcollective/annotations v5.4.2 requires illuminate/filesystem 5.4.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/filesystem[v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9].
    - don't install illuminate/filesystem v5.4.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.34
    - don't install illuminate/filesystem v5.4.13|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.34
    - don't install illuminate/filesystem v5.4.17|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.34
    - don't install illuminate/filesystem v5.4.19|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.34
    - don't install illuminate/filesystem v5.4.27|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.34
    - don't install illuminate/filesystem v5.4.36|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.34
    - don't install illuminate/filesystem v5.4.9|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.34
    - Installation request for laravel/framework == 5.5.34.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.5.34].
    - Installation request for laravelcollective/annotations ^5.4 -> satisfiable by laravelcollective/annotations[v5.4.0, v5.4.1, v5.4.2].
```

Comment: Considering their composer requires Laravel 5.4 and not any future versions `"illuminate/console": "5.4.*"`, I'm guessing that would be a no.

Comment: https://github.com/LaravelCollective/annotations/issues/68

Comment: Thank for your react... Do you know any other way where I can use a route annotation unless using `laravelcollective/annotations` ?

Comment: By looking through all of their [previous issues](https://github.com/LaravelCollective/annotations/issues?utf8=✓&q=), there's a fork for 5.5: https://github.com/montyclt/annotations

Comment: Thank you a lot... I try it and I'll go back to you soon

Answer (score 0):

it may be late for an answer, but maybe it will help someone

---

`"laravelcollective/annotations: 5.5.1"` version is not working clearly

`"laravelcollective/annotations: 5.5.1"` error contained in this: 
`Undefined property: Collective\Annotations\Routing\Annotations\ResourcePath::$no_prefix`

Comment: I read your answer several times but I found some hardship in understanding it. You want to say that laravel annotation 5.5.0 works fine with laravel 5.5.*, while laravel annotations 5.5.1 gives you the error you mentioned?.. You may consider rephrasing your answer to be more understandable

Comment: because my english is not good, sorry about this.
i want to say: laravel: 5.5.* with laravel annotations 5.5.1 gives the error, that's all

Comment: I'm not native either.. Take it easy, your language will get better over time for sure. If you edit your original answer it would be of much help since people usually give extra focus to the answer not the comment.